# Insert data into table at one time

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code

```
 echo    '<input type="submit" name="submit">';
```

I am getting the data from another table with this query

```
if($_POST['submit'])
 {
    $sql = mysql_query('SELECT q.username, q.firstanme,q.lastname FROM quizgroup q');
    foreach($sql as $s)
     {
        $username = $s->username;
        $firstname = $s->firstname;
        $lastname = $s->lastname;
        $sql = mysql_query('INSERT INTO user(username,firstname,lastname) VALUES('.$username.','.$first.','.$last.')');
     }
 }
```

Comment: How is that even inserting a single row considering you have strings that aren't encapsulated in quotes of some sort?

Comment: Please post the form you are submitting and some more php code

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
insert into user (SELECT username, firstanme, lastname FROM quizgroup)
```

This statement will copy the data from quizgroup to user table

Dont use "values" keyword when copy the data

Look at this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html